# Create Tidy Dataframe whith multiple time series and tags to enable groupby and Timeseries classification

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series, pivot

Dear all i have data that looks roughly like this:

```
|Serial     |    12345 | 12346  | ...
|Group      |    Shoes | T-shirt| ...
|...        |  ...     | ...    | ...
|Country    |     Uk   | DE     | ...
|2020_12    |     50   | 10     | ...
|2021_01    |     40   | 15     | ...
|2021_02    |     55   | 20     | ...
|2021_03    |     60   | 30     | ... <- Time Series with PRices Ends here
|...        |   ...    | ..     | ...
|pct_change_2021_01| -10 |5     | ... <- Pct change Time Series STarts here
|...        |   ...    | ..     | ...
```

Oritingally the data is simply Transposed. What whould be the best way to Strutkure this type of data so i can do mashine learing classification?

Would it be best to have just one value column with mutliple entries for each data like this, so the values like serial , Group, country etc are each dublicate in each row like it is often done with the "tidy dataframe" paradigm?

```
| Dat2    | Price | Serial | Group   |Country |
| 2020_12 |   50  |  12345 | Shoes   |  Uk    |
| 2020_12 |   10  |  12346 | T-shirt |  DE    |
| 2021_01 |   40  |  12345 | Shoes   |  Uk    |
| 2021_01 |   15  |  12346 | T-shirt |  DE    |
|                      ...                    |
```

If so how could i achive this? Or should i use the original datafram trasposed such that the values for different dates are simply saved in different columns and values for identical dates are in the same "Date Column"?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a good form of doing a machine learning project(Tidy data)

> - Each variable is a column
> - Each observation is a row
> - Each type of observational unit is a table

```
| Dat2    | Price | Serial | Group   |Country |
| 2020_12 |   50  |  12345 | Shoes   |  Uk    |
| 2020_12 |   10  |  12346 | T-shirt |  DE    |
| 2021_01 |   40  |  12345 | Shoes   |  Uk    |
| 2021_01 |   15  |  12346 | T-shirt |  DE    |
|                      ...                    |
```

Since it's a transposed dataframe

```
df_transposed
###

               0        1        2        3
Date     2020_12  2020_12  2020_01  2020_01
Price         50       10       40       15
Serial     12345    12346    12345    12346
Group      Shoes  T-shirt    Shoes  T-shirt
Country       UK       DE       UK       DE
```

We can transpose it again to flip back to the proper format like,

```
df_transposed.T
###
      Date Price Serial    Group Country
0  2020_12    50  12345    Shoes      UK
1  2020_12    10  12346  T-shirt      DE
2  2020_01    40  12345    Shoes      UK
3  2020_01    15  12346  T-shirt      DE
```

Since this is an oversimplified ETL part, I think it's much better to refer to Kaggle's notebooks related to **time series**,
e.g. [E-Commerce: Predicting Sales](https://www.kaggle.com/code/slehkyi/e-commerce-predicting-sales)